# Multiplication order of a Transform Matrix

Tags: rotation, scale, transformation, coordinate-transformation, rotational-matrices

I am having a major confusion on the order that should be followed in making the 2D transformation matrix. I'm currently referring to the below order.

**L = S × R × T**

L = local transformation matrix

S = local scale matrix

R = local rotation matrix

T = local translate matrix

Is this order is correct? Or is there any other order to follow.